# How can I initialize a value to my string array in a junit test?

Tags: java, arrays, string, junit, morse-code

How can I initialize value to my string array called texti. I need that to write a junit test (seen below)

```
    MorsenEnglisch s;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In setUpBeforeClass()");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In tearDownAfterClass()");
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In setUp()");
        s = new MorsenEnglisch();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In tearDown()");
        s = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void FirstTest() {
        System.out.println("In FirstTest.");
        s.setTexti();    // I don't know how to give texti a value right here. Texti should have only one
                         // field which holds the value "A".

        s.code(s);
        assertTrue(s.getOutput().equals(".- ")); //Since my program is a morse code translator it should 
                                                 //convert the letter A into .-
        // fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

Here is my class with all the methods. As you can see below the method "setTexti" is used to give Texti a value. I have no idea how to give Texti a value when I am writing the junit test. All the other names are pretty self-explanatory.

```
    private String[] texti;         // the whole text split up into an array
    private int amount;             // the number of fields in the array texti
    private String output = "";     // this is the translated text in a single string

    MorsenEnglisch() {
    }

    MorsenEnglisch(String[] texti, int amount) {
        this.texti = texti;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public void setTexti(String[] texti) {   //Here is the method that I need to use in my junit test
        this.texti = texti;
    }

    public void setOutput(String output) {
        this.output = output;
    }

    public void setAmount(int anzahl) {
        this.amount = anzahl;
    }

    public String[] getTexti() {
        return this.texti;
    }

    public String getOutput() {
        return this.output;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return this.amount;
    }

    public void code(MorsenEnglisch s) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= amount - 1; i++) {
            if (texti[i].equals("a") || texti[i].equals("A")) {
                texti[i] = ".- ";
                output = output + ".- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("b") || texti[i].equals("B")) {
                texti[i] = "-... ";
                output = output + "-... ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("c") || texti[i].equals("C")) {
                texti[i] = "-.-. ";
                output = output + "-.-. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("d") || texti[i].equals("D")) {
                texti[i] = "-.. ";
                output = output + "-.. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("e") || texti[i].equals("E")) {
                texti[i] = ". ";
                output = output + ". ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("f") || texti[i].equals("F")) {
                texti[i] = "..-. ";
                output = output + "..-. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("g") || texti[i].equals("G")) {
                texti[i] = "--. ";
                output = output + "--. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("h") || texti[i].equals("H")) {
                texti[i] = ".... ";
                output = output + ".... ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("i") || texti[i].equals("I")) {
                texti[i] = ".. ";
                output = output + ".. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("j") || texti[i].equals("J")) {
                texti[i] = ".--- ";
                output = output + ".--- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("k") || texti[i].equals("K")) {
                texti[i] = "-.- ";
                output = output + "-.- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("l") || texti[i].equals("L")) {
                texti[i] = ".-.. ";
                output = output + ".-.. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("m") || texti[i].equals("M")) {
                texti[i] = "-- ";
                output = output + "-- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("n") || texti[i].equals("N")) {
                texti[i] = "-. ";
                output = output + "-. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("o") || texti[i].equals("O")) {
                texti[i] = "--- ";
                output = output + "--- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("p") || texti[i].equals("P")) {
                texti[i] = ".--. ";
                output = output + ".--. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("q") || texti[i].equals("Q")) {
                texti[i] = "--.- ";
                output = output + "--.- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("r") || texti[i].equals("R")) {
                texti[i] = ".-. ";
                output = output + ".-. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("s") || texti[i].equals("S")) {
                texti[i] = "... ";
                output = output + "... ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("t") || texti[i].equals("T")) {
                texti[i] = "- ";
                output = output + "- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("u") || texti[i].equals("U")) {
                texti[i] = "..- ";
                output = output + "..- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("v") || texti[i].equals("V")) {
                texti[i] = "...- ";
                output = output + "...- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("w") || texti[i].equals("W")) {
                texti[i] = ".-- ";
                output = output + ".-- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("x") || texti[i].equals("X")) {
                texti[i] = "-..- ";
                output = output + "-..- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("y") || texti[i].equals("Y")) {
                texti[i] = "-.-- ";
                output = output + "-.-- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("z") || texti[i].equals("Z")) {
                texti[i] = "--.. ";
                output = output + "--.. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals(" ")) {
                texti[i] = " ";
                output = output + " ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("1")) {
                texti[i] = ".---- ";
                output = output + ".---- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("2")) {
                texti[i] = "..--- ";
                output = output + "..--- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("3")) {
                texti[i] = "...-- ";
                output = output + "...-- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("4")) {
                texti[i] = "....- ";
                output = output + "....- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("5")) {
                texti[i] = "..... ";
                output = output + "..... ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("6")) {
                texti[i] = "-.... ";
                output = output + "-.... ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("7")) {
                texti[i] = "--... ";
                output = output + "--... ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("8")) {
                texti[i] = "---.. ";
                output = output + "---.. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("9")) {
                texti[i] = "----. ";
                output = output + "----. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("0")) {
                texti[i] = "----- ";
                output = output + "----- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("ä") || texti[i].equals("Ä")) {
                texti[i] = ".-.- ";
                output = output + ".-.- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("ö") || texti[i].equals("Ö")) {
                texti[i] = "---. ";
                output = output + "---. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("ü") || texti[i].equals("Ü")) {
                texti[i] = "..-- ";
                output = output + "..-- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("ß")) {
                texti[i] = "...--.. ";
                output = output + "...--.. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals(".")) {
                texti[i] = ".-.-.- ";
                output = output + ".-.-.- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals(",")) {
                texti[i] = "--..-- ";
                output = output + "--..-- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals(":")) {
                texti[i] = "---... ";
                output = output + "---... ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals(";")) {
                texti[i] = "-.-.-. ";
                output = output + "-.-.-. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("?")) {
                texti[i] = "..--.. ";
                output = output + "..--.. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("-")) {
                texti[i] = "-....- ";
                output = output + "-....- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("_")) {
                texti[i] = "..--.- ";
                output = output + "..--.- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("(")) {
                texti[i] = "-.--. ";
                output = output + "-.--. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals(")")) {
                texti[i] = "-.--.- ";
                output = output + "-.--.- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("'")) {
                texti[i] = ".----. ";
                output = output + ".----. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("=")) {
                texti[i] = "-...- ";
                output = output + "-...- ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("+")) {
                texti[i] = ".-.-. ";
                output = output + ".-.-. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("/")) {
                texti[i] = "-..-. ";
                output = output + "-..-. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("@")) {
                texti[i] = ".--.-. ";
                output = output + ".--.-. ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("!")) {
                texti[i] = "-.-.-- ";
                output = output + "-.-.-- ";
            }
        }
    }

    public void decode(MorsenEnglisch s) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= amount - 1; i++) {
            if (texti[i].equals(".-")) {
                texti[i] = "A";
                output = output + "A";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("-...")) {
                texti[i] = "B";
                output = output + "B";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("-.-.")) {
                texti[i] = "C";
                output = output + "C";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("-..")) {
                texti[i] = "D";
                output = output + "D";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals(".")) {
                texti[i] = "E";
                output = output + "E";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("..-.")) {
                texti[i] = "F";
                output = output + "F";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("--.")) {
                texti[i] = "G";
                output = output + "G";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("....")) {
                texti[i] = "H";
                output = output + "H";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("..")) {
                texti[i] = "I";
                output = output + "I";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals(".---")) {
                texti[i] = "J";
                output = output + "J";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("-.-")) {
                texti[i] = "K";
                output = output + "K";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals(".-..")) {
                texti[i] = "L";
                output = output + "L";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("--")) {
                texti[i] = "M";
                output = output + "M";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("-.")) {
                texti[i] = "N";
                output = output + "N";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("---")) {
                texti[i] = "O";
                output = output + "O";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals(".--.")) {
                texti[i] = "P";
                output = output + "P";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("--.-")) {
                texti[i] = "Q";
                output = output + "Q";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals(".-.")) {
                texti[i] = "R";
                output = output + "R";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("...")) {
                texti[i] = "S";
                output = output + "S";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("-")) {
                texti[i] = "T";
                output = output + "T";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("..-")) {
                texti[i] = "U";
                output = output + "U";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("...-")) {
                texti[i] = "V";
                output = output + "V";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals(".--")) {
                texti[i] = "W";
                output = output + "W";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("-..-")) {
                texti[i] = "X";
                output = output + "X";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("-.--")) {
                texti[i] = "Y";
                output = output + "Y";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("--..")) {
                texti[i] = "Z";
                output = output + "Z";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("")) {
                texti[i] = " ";
                output = output + " ";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals(".----")) {
                texti[i] = "1";
                output = output + "1";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("..---")) {
                texti[i] = "2";
                output = output + "2";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("...--")) {
                texti[i] = "3";
                output = output + "3";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("....-")) {
                texti[i] = "4";
                output = output + "4";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals(".....")) {
                texti[i] = "5";
                output = output + "5";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("-....")) {
                texti[i] = "6";
                output = output + "6";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("--...")) {
                texti[i] = "7";
                output = output + "7";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("---..")) {
                texti[i] = "8";
                output = output + "8";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("----.")) {
                texti[i] = "9";
                output = output + "9";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("-----")) {
                texti[i] = "0";
                output = output + "0";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals(".-.-")) {
                texti[i] = "Ä";
                output = output + "Ä";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("---.")) {
                texti[i] = "Ö";
                output = output + "Ö";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("..--")) {
                texti[i] = "Ü";
                output = output + "Ü";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("...--..")) {
                texti[i] = "ß";
                output = output + "ß";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals(".-.-.-")) {
                texti[i] = ".";
                output = output + ".";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("--..--")) {
                texti[i] = ",";
                output = output + ",";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("---...")) {
                texti[i] = ":";
                output = output + ":";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("-.-.-.")) {
                texti[i] = ";";
                output = output + ";";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("..--..")) {
                texti[i] = "?";
                output = output + "?";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("-....-")) {
                texti[i] = "-";
                output = output + "-";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("..--.-")) {
                texti[i] = "_";
                output = output + "_";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("-.--.")) {
                texti[i] = "(";
                output = output + "(";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("-.--.-")) {
                texti[i] = ")";
                output = output + ")";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals(".----.")) {
                texti[i] = "'";
                output = output + "'";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("-...-")) {
                texti[i] = "=";
                output = output + "=";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals(".-.-.")) {
                texti[i] = "+";
                output = output + "+";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals("-..-.")) {
                texti[i] = "/";
                output = output + "/";
            }

            if (texti[i].equals(".--.-.")) {
                texti[i] = "@";
                output = output + "@";
            }
            if (texti[i].equals("-.-.--")) {
                texti[i] = "!";
                output = output + "!";
            }
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I never use the before and after set up.  I just init things in the test method directly, or I use a static final field for larger amounts of data.  This is nice because it keeps everything together so that someone reading the test can easily see exactly what it is doing.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

If I good understand you, you want to set the array with one element = "A". so, it is `s.setTexti(new String[]{"A"});`.

Comment: Yes you understood me correctly, kinda...  I already have a string array with the name "texti". I don't need a new one. I just need to give my already existing string array a value of one field. And that one field is supposed to contain the letter "A".

Comment: i don't see a place in pasted code where you are initializing the array. In `@Before` method you are creating the object (with constructor creating the object without any initializations) and nothing more -> so, the `texti` array is null. You have to pass a new array using setter.

Comment: @Uros Jandric, I don't think you understand correctly. By having `new String[]{}` as a method argument, you're not creating a referenceable object, like your String-Array texti. Think of it that `new String[]{"A"}` only creates a "temporary" object. It doesn't "create" a new String array you can use in later code, like you think.